# Does a binary built on pi 3 will work on pi 2?

Tags: qt

I'm building an app on a raspberry pi 3. I'm using Qt. Will the generated binary work on raspberry pi 2?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

- If you build for RPi1, CM1 and Zero it will run on any 32-bit OS on any model.
- If you build for 32-bit 2B it will run on 2B, 3B, 3B+, 3A+ or CM3.
- If you build for 3B, 3B+ 3A+ or CM3 it will only run on a model 3 - those are also able to run 64-bit.

[Compiler options for Raspberries](https://gist.github.com/fm4dd/c663217935dc17f0fc73c9c81b0aa845) has the full details.

Comment: This is erroneous. Depends on OS. NO current Raspbian uses or supports 64 bit code. Also depends on whether ARM6 or ARM7 code is generated. Virtually all Raspbian apps are compiled for ARM6.

Comment: @Milliways it has no dependency on any OS at all. The same is true if you run bare metal. BCM2835 code runs anywhere, BCM2836 code (original RPi2B) runs on 2B or 3B. BCM2837 code runs on model 3 (and some later model 2Bs).